# R data.table distance from ith element to every remaining element by group

Tags: r, data.table, distance

Suppose I have the following data:

```
d = data.table( id = 1, x = c(1, 10, 17, 35, 37, 45) )
```

I want to see if each ith element in x by group id has an element between 30 and 40 greater than it. So for the first element in x by group id (1), I am looking to see if any value in x after 1 is between the values 31 and 41. The answer is yes, so I'd like to create a column valid_gap that is TRUE for the first element. In the end, I'm looking to get:

```
d_final = data.table( id = 1, x = c(1, 10, 17, 35, 37, 45), valid_gap = c(T, T, F, F, F, F ) )
```

I've thought about this question with a colleague for a little while, and we're really trying to avoid using a loop here but can't figure it out. Is this possible without a loop?

My best attempt is something like:

```
d[, valid_gap := any(between( rdist(x[ .N - .I ])[,1], left = 30, right = 40 )), by = id]
```

but I'm thinking about the problem as trying to index through x as if in a loop, which I suspect is the wrong idea.

EDIT - "Bad" solution:

```
x = c(1, 10, 17, 35, 37, 45)
valid_gap = c()

for( i in 1:length(x) ) {
  if( i == length(x) ){
    valid_gap = c(valid_gap, F)
  } else {
    valid_gap = c(valid_gap, any(between( rdist( x[ x >= x[i] ] )[,1], left = 30, right = 40 )) )
  }
}
valid_gap
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess a non-equi join should be faster than a loop:

```
d[, v := 
  d[.(id = id, x0 = x + 30, x1 = x + 40), on=.(id, x >= x0, x <= x1), 
    .N
  , by=.EACHI][, N > 0L]
]

   id  x     v
1:  1  1  TRUE
2:  1 10  TRUE
3:  1 17 FALSE
4:  1 35 FALSE
5:  1 37 FALSE
6:  1 45 FALSE
```

For each row, we ...

1. find all matches in the interval of interest;
2. count them (with `.N`); and then
3. check if the count exceeds 0.

The first step might be marginally faster with `mult="first"`.

Comment: Also, it looks that a `findInterval` alternative could be `(i30 <- findInterval(x + 30, x)) & (findInterval(x + 40, x) > i30)`

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks, that's a cool way to do it. I think it's different enough for a separate answer, but can add it here if you'd prefer. I'd note the left.open option (so that x=c(0, 30) gives c(TRUE, FALSE)) or whatever else is relevant to tweaking the closed/openness of the interval (which isn't obvious to me with findInterval).

Comment: You 're right about the 'left.open = TRUE' one; missed that. It, also, accepts only sorted "x". Indeed `findInterval` needs a bit searching on how to use it -- few times I 've used a `Map` on an `expand.grid` of its arguments to investigate all possible uses... :). I guess it could be added in your answer -- wrapping it with a "by group" would make it even more close to your answer.

Comment: @alexis_laz Thanks, I was about to add it but then tested and realized ... my R 3.2.5 doesn't actually have that arg. It's too much hassle for me to update my work computer for it atm. Feel free to edit it in or post separately.

Answer (score 1):

```
library('data.table')
myfun <- function( y, z )
{
  any( z > y+30 & z < y+40 )  # check for values between the range
}
myfun <- Vectorize( FUN = myfun, vectorize.args = 'y')  # vectorize myfun() function for 'y' argument

d = data.table( id = 1, x = c(1, 10, 17, 35, 37, 45) )
d[, valid_gap := myfun(y = x, z = x ), by = .(id)]
d
#    id  x valid_gap
# 1:  1  1      TRUE
# 2:  1 10      TRUE
# 3:  1 17     FALSE
# 4:  1 35     FALSE
# 5:  1 37     FALSE
# 6:  1 45     FALSE
```

Comment: @vryb do you need row-6 with value 45 to be TRUE?

Comment: I've made an edit to the example data in my original question that I think demonstrates the problem more clearly. I don't think your approach works unfortunately, as it isn't checking 30 and 40 more than the ith value of x by group id, it is just checking for the values 30 and 40. Does my question make sense now? 17 should return F because there is no value between 17+30 and 17+40.

Comment: Here is the "bad" version of what I want to do:



`x = c(1, 10, 17, 35, 37, 45)

valid_gap = c()

for( i in 1:length(x) ) {
  
  if( i == length(x) ){

    valid_gap = c(valid_gap, F)

  } else {

    valid_gap = c(valid_gap, any(between( rdist( x[ x >= x[i] ] )[,1], left = 30, right = 40 )) )
 
 }
}
valid_gap`